# Why do clone variables still affect the original object? SWIFT

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, class, variables

Firstly, apologies if the question title didn't make much sense, was finding it tricky to word it correctly! I'm pretty confident in Objective-C but for a new project I've had to take on Swift (something i've been pretty apprehensive about).

Anyway, I've noticed something on a simple tableViewController tutorial that is driving me crazy.

First a new class is set up for each row with both a 'text' and 'checked' variable. An array is then made up of objects of this class to populate the table rows.

But in the tutorial maker's code, he changes the 'checked' property of a particular row using:

```
 let item = items[indexPath.row] 
 item.checked = !item.checked
```

Where `items[indexPath.row]` just picks out the required object in the array `items`. This is where I am confused, surely the first line creates a NEW clone object that is in no other way linked to the object in the array?

However, when changing any of `item`'s variables (e.g. how it swaps the state of `item.checked` that change is applied to the ORIGINAL array object `items[indexPath.row]` which just makes no logical sense?

Surely I would have to implement some kind of logic to make this happen, for example:

```
items[indexPath.row] = item
```

To apply all the changes to `item` back to the original object? Can someone please explain this backwards connection that is apparently there?

Thank you in advance, hopefully I'm just missing something simple!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up the difference between value types and reference types.
Basically you have a reference type. All classes are reference types.

```
//new class init
var myClassInstance : MyClass = MyClass()

// this creates a new reference to the original object
// changes will also happen to the original
var myClone = myClassInstance
```

Structs for example are value types. 
These copy the values and are not tied to the original

**Work around :**

You can create a custom initialiser that takes all necessary values from the original Class.

```
class MyCustomImageView : UIImageView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    init(uiImageView_I : UIImageView) {

        super.init(frame:uiImageView_I.frame)

        self.image = uiImageView_I.image
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

When you call the custom initialiser instead of the standard one, you will create separate instances each time.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, classes are reference types so there is no 'cloning' in this case - a reference is retrieved from the array and the properties of the instance it points to are modified. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID89